# Locking VSS programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-sourcesafe

My company currently uses VSS 5.0 (i know... terrible). We are looking for a way to lock all the users out programmatically. I looked through API and could not find any way to lock out anything other than checking out.

Basically I want to stop all users from checking in for a certain time period. Any ideas other than getting rid of VSS?

Was looking to code the application in C#

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to do that. The easiest way is to take down the VSS share, do what you need and then put the share back up. [Here](http://www.ckollars.org/backup.html#force)'s a link with a batch script which you can call from your C# code.